# Can base classes access methods of parent class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm trying to reduce redundant code by creating a base class that contains common methods and properties but I'm struggling as these common methods require inputs from parent objects.

Here is a simple example:

```py
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.raidus = radius
    def area(self):
        return 3.14 * self.radius**2
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * 3.14 * self.radius
    def perm_area(self):
        return self.perimeter() * self.area()

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width= width
        self.height = height
    def area(self):
        return self.width * self.height
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * self.height + 2 * self.width
    def perm_area(self):
        return self.perimeter() * self.area()
```

As you can see, both `Circle` and `Rectangle` classes have the same method where `perm_area = perimeter * area`.

I'd like to have a class called `Shape` that is inherited by both `Rectangle` and `Circle` but what would that class look like as it has no inputs and relies on it's parent object to be useful. The best I have is:

```py
class Shape:
    def __init__(self)
        pass

    def perm_area(self):
        return self.area * self.perimeter
```

The problem with this is that an error will be thrown that class `Shape` has no property `area` or `perimeter`

Obviously this code is oversimplified, but what would be a good solution to my problem? Specific classes, like circle and rectangle, that require inputs of differing structure that have common method names where each specif method has a unique formula, but produce a common result.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly base and parent class is same. I am assuming you meant can derived classes access methods of parent/base class? You have to decide whether you need to access the derived class Circle/Rectangle alone or both base and derived classes. 
In the first case, you can simply move function definition to base class, and since you will always use derived class only, your object will always have area and perimeter values.
Now if you need to access the method in both base as well as derived class, then initialize this variables(area, perimeter) in base to some default value like 0. That will take care of your exception saying area and perimeter are not defined.

> And so, YES derived classes can access methods of base classes.

Answer (score 0):

base class is synonym of parent class. If you want to reduce code and make performance faster then you need to put area and perimeter methods into base(parent) class. Here your child classes are circle and rectangle. So you need to use inheritance here and you can use base class methods into your child classes.

Comment: Thank you Nishi - would you be able to provide an example in code? How would the base class know which function to use to calculate area as it depends on what inherits it, circle or square. I suppose the answer will involve an if statement of sorts, but keep in mind this example only has 2 different area functions (circle and square), but my actual problem has about 25 unique "area" functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your base class to accept `kwargs`:

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.radius = kwargs.get("radius")
        self.width = kwargs.get("width")
        self.height = kwargs.get("height")

    @property
    def perimeter(self):
        if self.radius:
            return 2 * 3.14 * self.radius
        else:
            return 2 * self.height + 2 * self.width
```

Then you can create your `Circle` and `Rectangle` class that inherits from `Shape`:

```
class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        super().__init__(radius=radius)

    @property
    def area(self):
        return 3.14 * self.radius**2
    def perm_area(self):
        return self.perimeter * self.area

class Rectangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__(width=width,height=height)

    @property
    def area(self):
        return self.width * self.height
    def perm_area(self):
        return self.perimeter() * self.area
```

Comment: Thanks Henry! 
In my actual problem I have about 25 unique classes, like circle and square, that have different functions for their "area". Would I need an if statement for each one of these? Also width and height may not only be unique to rectangle which has its own area function but they might be the same inputs to say Triangle which has width and height inputs but a different area function than Rectangle. I'm looking for a pretty general solution.

Comment: I am not sure how general you want to get. Obviously you need a way to calculate areas for different shape - Python won't magically do it for you. You can put the methods as a dict, deduce a formula that suits for all cases, or use if else.